# Output results of my array is not as expected - php

Tags: php, arrays, output

So take this:

```
$status_choice = array();
$status_choice[] = "New Job";               
$status_choice[] = "Existing Case";
```

Now I use it:

```
dropdown("Status:","status",$status_choice,"150px");
```

This is basically a function to output a html dropdown. But instead of those values of the array coming up in the dropdown, it comes up like below:

[image: Dropdown showing two options, "e" and "x"]

Here my dropdown() function:

```
function dropdown($title,$name,$possible_values,$width="300px",$desc="",$onchange="") {

    global $dropdown_allow_nulls;

    $current_value = $GLOBALS["row_$name"];
    if ($current_value == "") { $current_value = $GLOBALS["form_$name"]; }

    if (is_write_lock()) {
        return dropdown_readonly($title, $name, $possible_values, $width, $desc, $onchange);
    }

    $myonchange = "";

    //if ($onchange != "") { $myonchange = "onChange=\"set_control_changed(this); $onchange\""; } else { $myonchange = "onChange=\"set_control_changed(this);\""; }

    if ($GLOBALS["myclass"] != $GLOBALS["myclass1"]) { $GLOBALS["myclass"] = $GLOBALS["myclass1"]; } else { $GLOBALS["myclass"] = $GLOBALS["myclass2"]; }
    $myclass = $GLOBALS["myclass"];

    print "<tr class=\"$myclass\">\n";
    print "<td style=\"padding-right: 10px;\">$title</td>\n";
    print "<td style=\"padding-bottom: 2px; padding-top: 1px;\">\n";

    print "<select name=\"$name\" $myonchange style=\"width: $width;\" id=\"form_$name\">\n";

    if (is_array($possible_values)) {

        if ($dropdown_allow_nulls == 1) {

            $key = "";
            $value = "";
            if ($key == $current_value) { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }

            print "<option value=\"$key\" $selected>$value</option>\n";

        }

        foreach ($possible_values as $myrow) {

            $key = $myrow[0];
            $value = $myrow[1];
            if ($key == $current_value) { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }

            print "<option value=\"$key\" $selected>$value</option>\n";

        }

    } else {

        // sql query

        $myquery = sql_query($possible_values);
        print sql_error();

        if ($dropdown_allow_nulls == 1) {

            $key = "";
            $value = "";
            if ($key == $current_value) { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }

            print "<option value=\"$key\" $selected>$value</option>\n";

        }

        while ($myrow = sql_fetch_row($myquery)) {

            $key = $myrow[0];
            $value = $myrow[1];
            if ($key == $current_value) { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }

            print "<option value=\"$key\" $selected>$value</option>\n";

        }

    }

    print "</select>\n";

    if ($desc) {
        print "<span style=\"margin-left: 10px; color: #888888;\">$desc</span>\n";
    }

    print "</td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";

}
```

Comment: What values are you expecting to get for `$key` and `$value` in the loop which is iterating over `$possible_values`? As it is, each element in `$possible_values` is only a value. Are you using the auto-incrementing array indices as your `$key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$myrow[1]` will get second character of the $myrow, either change `$value = $myrow[1]` to `$value = $myrow`, or change below code

```
foreach ($possible_values as $myrow) {

    $key = $myrow[0];
    $value = $myrow[1];
    if ($key == $current_value) { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }

    print "<option value=\"$key\" $selected>$value</option>\n";

}
```

With below and try

```
foreach ($possible_values as $key => $value) {
    $selected = $key == $current_value ? 'selected' : '';
    print "<option value=\"$key\" $selected>$value</option>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach ($possible_values as $myrow) {

        $key = $myrow[0];
        $value = $myrow[1];
```

At this point, `$myrow` is a string, first "New Job" and then "Existing Case". As such, `$key` is being set to `N` and `E`, while `$value` is being set to `e` and `x`.

Use:

```
foreach($possible_values as $key=>$value) {
```

instead.

Comment: Now i get two empty dropdown values

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get character array of the value. You need to get the key and value part of the main array and not of the values (which will change it to character array). Change the following lines:

```
...
foreach ($possible_values as $key=>$value) {

       // $key = $myrow[0];
       // $value = $myrow[1];
        if ($key == $current_value) { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }

        print "<option value=\"$key\" $selected>$value</option>\n";

    }
...
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: You are trying to get character array of the value. You need to get the key and value part of the main array and not of the values (which will change it to character array)